# Возможно ли комбинировать несколько способов синхронизации?

Tags: java, многопоточность, синхронизация, concurrency

Здравствуйте.
Изучаю синхронизацию потоков в Java, и, как я понял из книги, существует несколько способов синхронизации: через ключевое слово `synchronized`, через использование блокировок `ReentrantLock` и через методы `wait`/`notify`.

1. Правильно ли я выделил эти способы?
2. Эти способы самодостаточны? Можно ли каждый из них использовать, не прибегая к остальным?
3. Комбинация этих способов невозможна/нежелательна/допустима/желательна?

Comment: Кроме `ReentrantLock` в `java.util.concurrent` есть масса других интересных вещей на разные случаи жизни. `synchronized` - простое грубое решение, пока вас не интересует производительность. `wait/notify` - очень низкоуровневые операции, нужно понимать как они работают, но пользоваться чем-то более высокоуровневым.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Давайте по пунктам:

1. Нет, не верно. пара методов `wait()/notify()` работают только в `synchronized` блоке. Следовательно, они не могут быть выделены в отдельную категорию. Для разграничения доступа к разделяемому ресурсу используют:

   - `synchronized` блок, или метод.
   - некоторые абстракции, в виде реализации интерфейса `java.util.concurrent.Lock`, различные семафоры, барьеры и пр. Их типы с избытком представлены в пакете `java.util.concurrent`. Впрочем, никто не запрещает написать какую нибудь свою реализацию.

2 и 3. Способы самодостаточны и их вполне, можно использовать не смешивая. Но как правило, в многопоточных программах, могут встретиться несколько типов синхронизации. Все сильно зависит от логики и условий использования. Приведу лишь несколько примеров:

- если к ресурсу обращаются не так часто и не много потоков, то производительнее будет использовать блокировку основанную на CAS'ах, т.к. это позволяет покрутившись в цикле избежав парковки треда, захватить ресурс, пускай и затратив некоторое процессорное время.
- если у ресурса есть два режима: чтение и запись и относительно мало потоков, которые в него пишут, то используется `java.util.concurrent.ReadWriteLock`. Это позволяет нескольким *потокам-читателям* заходить в критические области. Но если появляется *писатель*, то *читатели* ждут, когда завершится чтение.

Answer (score 4):

1. synchronized, wait, notify и notifyAll работают в связке - это примитивы. ReentrantLock - это высокоуровневая конструкция и реализована она через примитивы.
2. Вы можете сами создать высокоуровневые конструкции из примитивов, но придется хорошо продумать архитектуру.
3. Обычно используют высокоуровневые конструкции, а не приметивы, но вы можете их смешивать, если это необходимо.